# Jupiter saves an empty photo, although it shows it before. How to fix that?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm reading and output the picture as a plot:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

path = 'photo.jpg'
im = plt.imread(path)
ax.imshow(im)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj8wV.png)

After I want to save it and check(see) the image before saving, but my code generate empty image:(

```
plt.axis("off")
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.NullLocator())
filename = os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0]
output_path = os.path.join("test", filename+".png").replace("/", "")
plt.savefig(output_path, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.0)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgu9W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to read the image as a graph?

If not, just use `PIL` library. It is a way more simpler to use:

[image]

You can check the code there: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Dmhb4aiERRym9bNx5HgCQPOr9iANHMic?usp=sharing

PIL documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or links small blocks of code, include it as properly formatted code in the text. Please [edit] your answer accordingly